# If $f$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism between open subsets of Banach spaces, is ${\rm D}f$ surjective at each point?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, frechet-derivative, diffeomorphism

Let $E_i$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, $\Omega_i\subseteq E_i$ be open and $f:\Omega_1\to\Omega_2$ be bijective. If $f$ is Fréchet differentiable at $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$ and $f^{-1}$ is Fréchet differentiable at $\omega_2:=f(\omega_1)$, then $f^{-1}\circ f$ is Fréchet differentiable at $\omega_1$ and $$\operatorname{id}_{E_1}={\rm D}\operatorname{id}_{\Omega_1}(\omega_1)={\rm D}(f^{-1}\circ f)(\omega_1)={\rm D}f^{-1}(\omega_2)\circ{\rm D}f(\omega_1)\tag1.$$ Can we conclude that ${\rm D}f(\omega_1)$ is surjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If instead of differentiating $f^{-1}\circ f$ you differentiate $f\circ f^{-1}$, you get 
$$
\operatorname{id}_{E_2}={\rm D}\operatorname{id}_{\Omega_2}(\omega_2)={\rm D}(f\circ f^{-1})(\omega_2)={\rm D}f (\omega_1)\circ{\rm D}f^{-1}(\omega_2)\tag2.
$$
So $Df(\omega_1)$ is invertible.

Comment: Most probably, you didn't noticed and copied my equation $(1)$ to form your equation $(2)$, but on the left-hand side of these equation it should be $\operatorname{id}_{E_1}$ instead of $\operatorname{id}_{\Omega_2}(\omega_2)=\omega_2$.

Comment: Indeed. $\ \ \ $

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not correct. You need to remove the evaluation on the left-hand side.

Comment: Yes, I didn't even stop to think.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something, but if ${\rm D}f(\omega_1)$ is a surjective (even bijective) function from $E_1$ to $E_2$, then $E_1$ and $E_2$ need to have the same dimension ... But this clearly doesn't need to be the case. Where is my fault in thinking here?

Comment: "Clearly doesn't need to be the case". Example?

Comment: Well, the example which led me back to this question was the local parametrization $f$ of a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$. Here $E_1=\mathbb R^d$ and $E_2=\mathbb R^k$. I guess the point is that we can only conclude that it is surjective, but not injective.

Comment: But if $k<d$, your manifold is not open.

Comment: The whole manifold is not open, but for each point in its manifold interior there is an open neighborhood diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^k$.

Comment: Well, yes, but those are not the conditions in your question. And you would have to clarify what you mean by "Frechet differentiable" if your domain is not open.

Comment: I mean that there is an open neighborhood of its domain and an extension which is Fréchet differentiable on this neighborhood.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I miss something or not. So, I've asked this as a [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3752551/47771). I've explained everything in more detail there.